# Image recognition for PCB - is this available?

Tags: software

I have a populated PCB, and I want to draw a circuit diagram of it.

For printed documents, you have OCR which can recognize text in an image. Is something similar available for PCBs? i.e. I provide photos of the front and back of the PCB, and the software recognizes the components, their values and how they're connected?

I realize this would be limited (the sw can't see PCB traces covered by components, multilayer PCB etc), but is it possible at all?

Comment: How complex are the PCBs you want to analyze? This _might_ work for very oldish 2-layer PCBs, but modern PCBs have 20 layers or so. No way these can be analyzed with a camera.

Comment: the one I'm looking at now is a simple 1-layer PCB.

Comment: Do you want to automate it for multiple PCBs or do you want it for one?

Comment: Some carbon based units can do it.

Comment: I've got only one PCB at the moment. I can figure this one out by hand, just wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Even if there is such a tool, it would be highly unreliable. Even humans can't do it using vision only, they need to use other tools too

Comment: Check it out: https://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic3247421.html